# Как не показывать див с содержанием display:none кроссбраузерно

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, frontend

Для того, чтобы не показывать пустой див я использую псевдокласс `:empty`. Но нужно скрывать не только пустой див, но и див в котором содержимому прописан стиль `display:none`, и он только выглядит как пустой, и на самом деле в нем есть `html` код. Существует ли способ, скрыть такой блок? Желательно с помощью только `css`.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
div:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<br>Див:
<br><div>123</div>
<br><br>
<br>Див с пробелом:
<br><div>&nbsp;</div>
<br><br>
<br>Пустой див:
<br><div></div>
<br><br>
<br>Див с содержимим:
<br><div>
  <section>456</section>
</div>
<br><br>
<br>Див с содержимим со стилем display:none:
<br><div>
  <section style="display: none;">789</section>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: вообще ничего не понял!

Comment: @Air пустой див скрыть просто, с помощью псевдокласса, но вот если его делать пустым путем прописывания дисплей нон для ребенка, то псевдокласс не будет работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью `css` только в теории, с использованием селектора `:has`, но пока не поддерживают его браузеры (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)

```
div:has(> section[style*="display:block"]) {
    display: none;
}
```

Но через `jQuery` с использованием такого же селектора должно работать

```
$("div:has(section[style*=`display:block`]").hide()
```